# How to export matplotlib file to kml

Tags: python, matplotlib, kml

I'm trying to export a matplotlib figure using a kml format. The question is identical to the following:

[Export Python Plot to KML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31709437/export-python-plot-to-kml)

I've outlined the exact function but I can't get the kml output to work. Conversely, if I export a `simplekml` function, it's working fine.

I've attached both outputs below. Output 1 one works but 2 doesn't.

Output 1:

```
import simplekml
kml = simplekml.Kml()
kml.newpoint(name="Kirstenbosch", coords=[(18.432314,33.988862)])
kml.save("botanicalgarden.kml")
```

[image]

But when trying to pass a matplotlib function to simplekml function, I'm returning the following output. What am I doing wrong?

Output 2:

```
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as ppl
from pylab import rcParams
import simplekml
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (8,8)

# create rectangle over 0 to 10 degrees longitude and 0 to 10 degrees latitude
x = [0, 10, 10, 0, 0]
y = [10, 10, 0, 0, 10]
x1 = range(0,11)    # to draw a diagonal line

fig = ppl.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.axis('off')
fig.patch.set_facecolor('blue')  # so we can see the true extent

ppl.plot(x, y, 'r', linewidth=3)
ppl.plot(x, y, '.b', linewidth=3)
ppl.plot(x1, x1, 'g', linewidth=3)

ppl.axis('off')
border1 = ppl.axis()

if False:
    ppl.show()
else:
    pngName = 'Overlay.png'
    fig.savefig(pngName, facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), transparent=False)

bottomleft  = (border1[0],border1[2])
bottomright = (border1[1],border1[2])
topright    = (border1[1],border1[3])
topleft     = (border1[0],border1[3])

kml = simplekml.Kml()
ground = kml.newgroundoverlay(name='GroundOverlay')
ground.icon.href = pngName
ground.gxlatlonquad.coords =[bottomleft, bottomright, topright, topleft]
kml.save("GroundOverlay.kml")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you have done the following:

```
pip install matplotlib
pip install basemap
pip install simplekml
```

Versions I have installed:

```
Matplotlib version: 3.7.1
Basemap version: 1.3.7  
Simplekml version: 1.3.2
```

How to find the versions you have installed from command line:

```
python -c "import matplotlib; import mpl_toolkits.basemap; import simplekml; print('Matplotlib version:', matplotlib.__version__); print('Basemap version:', mpl_toolkits.basemap.__version__); print('Simplekml version:', simplekml.__version__)"
```

Moreover, Check that you are in the correct working directory. Additionally, ensure you have the necessary permissions in the target directory. If the program does not have write permissions, it will not be able to save the KML file. Furthermore, check for compatibility issues: It's possible that there may be compatibility issues between the versions of `mpl_toolkits.basemap` and `matplotlib` you are using.

Lastly, I was able to run your code just fine. See image below:
[image: Example image for Chopin]

The code that you provided: [image: The code that Chopin provided]

Comment: can you update your answer detailing the versions of ```matplotlib```, ```basemap``` and ```simplekml``` that you had installed, this will illustrate the compatibility between the products as an example.

Comment: Good idea, @djmonki. I will do that now.

This request has been fulfilled, I have further added a command to the post that via command line helps them check their versions too.

Comment: Sorry for the delay on this. I created a new environment from scratch. Still getting same output. I have the exact same versions installed. I had issues with the installation of `mpl_toolkits.basemap`. I think there's an issue there but I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: How do I check the necessary permissions in the target directory? Also, how do I check compatibility version of `mpl_toolkits.basemap` and `matplotlib`

Comment: If Output works then the permissions should be functional right? Or not necessarily.

Comment: 'mpl_toolkits.basemap' Is not actively developed any longer -- depreciated. It would be a good idea to look into Cartopy. However, with regards to your question I would start with 'pip install --upgrade pip' Once you've done this it will update your Python and PIP.
Its good practice to create a virtual environment for your project, this will help you avoid conflicts between package versions. 
'python -m venv myenv
source myenv\Scripts\activate'
I've found that installing basemap sometimes directly through PIP does not always work, try Anaconda; it handles deps for geospatial libs better.

Comment: Moreover, it is also worth noting that Basemap requires compilation, so CPP, have you installed CPP? [visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools IIRC there is another dependency you'll need if you're on windows- however, I don't remember what it was off hand, possibly lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs Anyhow, as aforementioned, its best to avoid this anyway, as its depreciated.
With regards to permissions are you on Linux, Windows or Mac? If you're on windows run your command prompt as Administrator. So in my case since I am using the prompt within Visual Studio Code, id run Visual Studio

Comment: Code as Administrator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254400/discussion-between-devils-nerve-and-chopin).